# In Sendmail Jilter, what does various Abbreviations mentioned in JilterConstants mean

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail, postfix-mta, milter

In Sendmail Jilter, what does various Abbreviations mentioned in JilterConstants mean ?
like:
`SMFIC_HEADER`, `SMFIR_CHGHEADER` etc.

Official documentation doesn't have any details for class `JilterConstants`

http://sendmail-jilter.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html

However i was able to find what each flag is used for:

https://github.com/tachtler/jilter-InfoMilter/blob/master/com/sendmail/jilter/JilterConstants.java

But i am interested in full form of those flags.

For `SMFIC_HEADER` I assume it may mean "Send Mail Flag .... " But i am looking for an official reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The constants are copied from Milter API (libmilter) as provided by sendmail.org.

Milter API (libmilter) is documented in open source `sendmail` distribution files.